# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \log x}{1+x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

In order to compute, in an **elementary way**,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan x \log \left( 1-x^2\right)}{1+x^2}dx$

(see  [Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan x \log \left( 1-x^2\right)}{1+x^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542741/evaluating-int-01-fracx-arctan-x-log-left-1-x2-right1x2dx))

i need to show, in a **simple way**, that:

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\arctan x \log x}{1+x}dx=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}-\dfrac{\pi^3}{64}$

$G$ is the Catalan's constant.

Comment: What is your question? What does *simple way* mean? Do you already know some other way which you are not satisfied with?

Comment: Moreover, why do you think there is an *elementary way* to evaluate the linked integral?

Comment: "simple way": use of change of variable, double, triple integrals, derivation under integral and such stuff. Anyway, if you have a solution, whatever it's, i'm interrested. I don't know if a simple solution do exist.

Answer (score 22):

I finally get a solution (i swear i didn't know it when i have posted the question)

Define for $x\in [0,1]$ the function $F$:

$\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^x \dfrac{\ln t}{1+t}dt$

Notice that $F(1)=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$

(use Taylor's development)

and, after performing the change of variable $y=\dfrac{t}{x}$,

$\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(xy)}{1+xy}dy$

Since that:

$\Big[F(x)\arctan x\Big]_0^1=-\dfrac{\pi^3}{48}$

then,

$\displaystyle -\dfrac{\pi^3}{48}=\int_0^1 \dfrac{F(x)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^1 \dfrac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}dx$

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{F(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(xy)}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)}dxdy$

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{F(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(x)}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)}dxdy+\int_0^1\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(y)}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)}dxdy$

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{F(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\left[\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+xy)}{1+x^2}\right]_{y=0}^{y=1} dx+
\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left[-\dfrac{\ln y\ln(1+xy)}{1+y^2}+\dfrac{\ln y\ln(1+x^2)}{2(1+y^2)}+\dfrac{y\ln y\arctan x}{1+y^2}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}dy$

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{F(x)}{1+x^2}dx= \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln y\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}dy+\dfrac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln y}{1+y^2}dy+
\dfrac{\pi}{4}\times \int_0^1 \dfrac{y\ln y}{1+y^2}dy$

Using Taylor's development,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{y\ln y}{1+y^2}dy=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{48}$

And it's well known that, $\displaystyle -G=\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln y}{1+y^2}dy$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{F(x)}{1+x^2}dx=-\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}-\dfrac{\pi^3}{192}$

And finally,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\arctan x \ln x}{1+x}dx=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}-\dfrac{\pi^3}{64}$

(I hope there is no mistake, this proof is too wonderful to be true )

NB:

**Added, July 2, 2019.**

The above computation is the result of "reverse engineering".
I was searching for a way to express $\pi^3$ as in integral.
If you introduce the function, for $x\in [0;1]$,
\begin{align}\displaystyle F(x)&=\int_0^x \dfrac{\ln t}{1+t}dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(tx)}{1+tx}dt
\end{align}
Observe that,
\begin{align}\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x}&=\dfrac{\ln x}{1+x}\\
F(1)&=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}

Then,
\begin{align}-\frac{\pi^3}{48}&=\Big[F(x)\arctan x\Big]_0^1\\
\end{align}
And, 
\begin{align}\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x}\arctan x=\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}\end{align}

Thus, one can apply integration by parts,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x}\arctan x\,dx\end{align}
and so on,

Comment: If there is no error. It's too wonderful to be true , i can't believe that's true

Comment: I am not able to spot any mistake. It is a nice trick to work with two variables, it happens very often that by sticking to single-variable manipulations life gets hard in these cases.

Comment: very elegant approach.

Comment: Hi FDP, I found a generalization for $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\ln^{a}(x)}{1+x}dx$ using your method. Do you mind if I include it in my upcoming article and I cite your solution?

Answer (score 8):

Let we deal with a basic problem first, i.e. the computation of
$$ C_{2n+1} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n+1}\log x}{1+x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t e^{-(2n+2)t}}{1+e^{-t}}\,dt\tag{1}$$
Since $\int_{0}^{+\infty}t e^{-mt}\,dt = \frac{1}{m^2}$, we have:
$$ -C_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{(2n+2)^2}-\frac{1}{(2n+3)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n+4)^2}-\ldots=\frac{\psi'(n+1)-\psi'\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{4}\tag{2}$$
and:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)\log(x)}{1+x}\,dx = -\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n C_{2n+1}}{2n+1}=-\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{(2n+1)(2n+m+2)^2}\tag{3}$$
By reindexing the last double series,
$$ I = -\sum_{s=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{s}\frac{(-1)^s}{(2p+1)(p+s+2)^2}=-\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{s\geq p}\frac{(-1)^s}{(p+s+2)^2(2p+1)}\tag{4}$$
hence, in terms of the [Hurwitz zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html):
$$ I = -\sum_{p\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^p}{4(p+1)}\left(\zeta\left(2,p+1\right)-\zeta\left(2,p+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\tag{5}$$
or, by using the inverse Laplace transform:
$$ I = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s e^{s/2}\log(1+e^{-s})}{4(1+e^{s/2})}\,ds =-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s e^s \log(1+e^{-2s})}{1+e^s}\,ds\tag{6}$$
where the last integral is a bit more manageable than the initial one (we made the arctangent function disappear). The constants $K,\log 2$ and 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32} \tag{7}$$
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas) for the last identity) should simply appear by integration by parts.

---

With a suitable change of variable and differentiation under the integral sign, we may probably also exploit the integral remainder term in [the second Binet's formula for $\log\Gamma$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html).

Comment: Very Nice :) (+1)

Comment: Nice but too clever for me

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

set $x=e^{-y}$ we have
\begin{align}
  & \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{\tan }^{-1}}x\,\,\ln x}{1+x}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty }{\,\frac{-y\,{{e}^{-y}}{{\tan }^{-1}}({{e}^{-y}})\,}{1+{{e}^{-y}}}}\,dy \\ 
\\
 & {-{e}^{-y}}{{\tan }^{-1}}({{e}^{-y}})=-{e}^{-y}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n+1}}}{2n-1}{{e}^{-(2n-1)y}}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n}}}{2n-1}{{e}^{-2n\,y}}} \\ 
\\
 & \frac{1}{1+{{e}^{-y}}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{{{(-1)}^{n}}{{e}^{-ny}}} \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: ok, but what now?

Comment: so complex but it is heuristic.

Comment: factor $ln x$ isn't the problem. $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^n\ln x dx=-\dfrac{1}{(1+n)^2}$

Comment: Do you really know if this hint actually leads to an elementary way of computing the integral? Judging by your comment it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long solution but I hope you find it useful.

First lets consider the integral:
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x}{x(1+x)}\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}\ln x}{1+x}\ dx\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial{n}}\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}\ dx\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial{n}}\left(H_n-H_{2n}+\ln2\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\left(2H_{2n}^{(2)}-H_n^{(2)}-\zeta(2)\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\left(2H_{2n}^{(2)}-H_n^{(2)}\right)-\frac{\pi^3}{48}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

on the other hand,
\begin{align*}
I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x}{x(1+x)}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x}{x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x}\ dx\tag{2}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*} 
\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x}{x}\ dx&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_0^1x^{2n}\ln x\ dx=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=-\frac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{align*}

we can conclude from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x}\ dx&=-\frac{\pi^3}{96}-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\left(2H_{2n}^{(2)}-H_n^{(2)}\right)\\
&=-\frac{\pi^3}{96}-\frac12\left(2S_1-S_2\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}
\begin{align}
S_1&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}^{(2)}}{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}^{(2)}}{2n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&\boxed{=\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac{\pi^3}{32}=S_1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
S_2&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}^{(2)}}{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nH_n^{(2)}\int_0^1x^{2n}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n^{(2)}(-x^2)^n\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx \quad \text{ apply IBP}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}+2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\ dx\tag{#}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{2n+1}\int_0^1x^{2n}\ dx\\
&=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}+4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}+4\times\frac{\pi^3}{32}\\
&\boxed{=-4\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n}{n^2}+\frac{5\pi^3}{48}=S_2}
\end{align}
note that in line $\text{(#)}$, we used $\ \displaystyle\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n H_{2n}} {2n+1}x^{2n+1}\ $ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240779/prove-ln1x2-arctan-x-2-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-h-2n2n1x2n1)).

Plugging $S_1$ and $S_2$ in $(3)$, we get $$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}\ dx=\frac{7\pi^3}{96}-\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n^{(2)}}{n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n}{n^2}\right)$$

using the generating functions:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n^{(2)}}{n}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)-\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)-\zeta(2)\ln(1-x)-2\zeta(3)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln^2x\ln(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$
then 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n^{(2)}}{n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n}{n^2}&=3\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\ln(1-x)\{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\ln x\ln(1-x)-\zeta(2)\}\\
&=3\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)
\end{align}
where in the last line, we used the reflection identity. taking $x=i$ , we get
\begin{align}
\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n^{(2)}}{n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n}{n^2}\right)&=\Im\left(3\operatorname{Li}_3(i)-\ln(1-i)\operatorname{Li}_2(i)\right)\\
&=\frac{17\pi^3}{192}-\frac12G\ln2
\end{align}
which follows 
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}\ dx&=\frac{7\pi^3}{96}-\left(\frac{17\pi^3}{192}-\frac12G\ln2\right)\\
&=\frac12G\ln2-\frac{\pi^3}{64}
\end{align}

Comment: Any thoughts on how to sum those Euler sums?

Comment: @omegadot the first sum is easy, as for the second one , I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @omegadot you can see a full solution now. I did little manipulation with these two sums. they can be evaluated separately but I chose a short cut. hope you like it.

Comment: Very nice. The magic key here to evaluating these Euler sums is by using appropriate generating functions evaluated at $x = i$.

Comment: @omegadot yes i would say thats the key but i am sure there is a much shorter hidden way to manipulate with these two sums. i will investigate into that.

Answer (score 2):

**Different approach:**

start with applying integration by parts

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)\ln(x)}{1+x}dx\\=\left|(\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)+\ln(x)\ln(1+x))\tan^{-1}(x)\right|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)+\ln(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{1+x^2}dx-\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx}\tag1$$

---

From $$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=-\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(y)}{1-xy}dy$$

it follows that

$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(y)}{1+xy}dy\right)dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\ln(y)\left(\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+x^2)(1+yx)}dx\right)dy$$

$$=\int_0^1\ln(y)\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{y}{1+y^2}-\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}+\frac{\ln(2)}{2(1+y^2)}\right)dy$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^3}{192}-\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(y)\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}dy}-\frac12\ln(2)\ G\tag2$$

By plugging $(2)$ in $(1)$, the blue integral magically cancels out and we get $I=\frac12G\ln2-\frac{\pi^3}{64}$.

Comment: @omegadot i think you will like this answer :)

Comment: I do indeed. Now if only one could find a value for the blue integral. It pops up in a number of problems like this which I have seen, before magically disappearing again.

Comment: @omegadot I think the blue integral is manageable we can just evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{1+x^2}dx$ by converting the boundaries from $(0,1)$ to $(0,\infty)$ and we follow the same steps above.