# Integration by parts: is this legitimate way of using?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is it legitimate to write 
$$\int_0^a\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)g(x)=\left[f(x)\int_0^x\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)\right]_0^a-\int_0^a\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^x\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)$$

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is correct. Even if you remove the limits 0 to x in the $\int_0^xg(x)dx$ it will be fine.

Comment: You should use two different integration variables in the last *double* integral.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a non-trivial example of using the formula involved in your question please consider reading http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1842492

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's good, if read correctly; you are less likely to make errors with this if you set
$$
G(x)=\int_0^xg(t)\,dt
$$
and write
$$
\int_0^af(x)g(x)\,dx=
\Bigl[f(x)G(x)\Bigr]_0^a-\int_0^a f'(x)G(x)\,dx
$$
If you prefer not to use $G$, you can write
$$
\int_0^af(x)g(x)\,dx=
\left[f(x)\int_0^x g(t)\,dt\right]
-
\int_0^a f'(x)\left(\int_0^x g(t)\,dt\right)\,dx
$$

Comment: Yes! It's better to introduce the new variable $t$ than to use $x$ for two different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!It is correct
Let $u=f(x)$, $dv=g(x)dx$,

$du=f'(x)dx, v=\int_{0}^{a}g(x)dx$
so

$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)g(x)dx=[f(x)\int_{0}^{x}g(x)dx]_{0}^{a}-\int_{0}^{a}[\int_{0}^{x}g(x)dx]f'(x)dx $

Next, integrate by parts a second time,

$u=f'(x)dx, dv=\int_{0}^{a}g(x)dx$

$du=f''(x)dx, v=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}g(x)(dx)^{2}$

$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)g(x)dx=[f(x)\int_{0}^{x}g(x)dx]_{0}^{a}-[f'(x)\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}g(x)(dx)^{2}]_{0}^{a}+\int_{0}^{a}[\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}g(x)(dx)^{3}]f''(x)dx $

Comment: why are you integrating a second time? and also be careful with your integration variables. as of now, your integrals are not all well defined

Comment: I was trying to give the idea that, what happens after  $n$ applications. It is not important using different integration variables, when you understand  the variables of integration. That does not mean that you are wrong.  "A Way of Writing"

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but not quite.  I'm seeing a lot of notational issues and other issues around here which could lead to trouble.  Instead, say:

$u = f(x), \qquad dv = g(x) \, dx$

$du = f'(x)\, dx, \qquad v = \displaystyle \int_0^x g(t) \, dt + v(0)\qquad $ (this $v$ is explained later in the post)

Then we have

$$ \int_0^a f(x) g(x) \, dx = \left[f(x) \left(\int_0^x g(t)\, dt + v(0)\right)\right]\Bigg|_{x=0}^{x=a} - \int_0^a \left(\int_0^x g(t)\, dt + v(0)\right) f'(x) \, dx $$

Here's a breakdown of what's what in the formula:

$$ \overbrace{\int_0^a \underbrace{f(x)}_{\color{red}{u}} \underbrace{g(x) \, dx}_{\color{red}{dv}}}^{\color{blue}{\int_{x=0}^{x=a} u \, dv}} = \overbrace{\left[\underbrace{f(x)}_{\color{red}{u}} \underbrace{\left(\int_0^x g(t)\, dt + v(0)\right)}_{\color{red}{v}}\right]\Bigg|_{x=0}^{x=a}}^{\color{blue}{uv\big|_{x=0}^{x=a}}} - \overbrace{\int_0^a \underbrace{\left(\int_0^x g(t)\, dt + v(0)\right)}_{\color{red}{v}} \underbrace{f'(x) \, dx}_{\color{red}{du}}}^{\color{blue}{\int_{x=0}^{x=a} v \, du}} $$

---

Some explanations:

We already know that $dv = g(x) \, dx$.  Therefore $v'(x) = g(x)$, and the FTC tells us that $\int_0^x v'(t) \, dt = v(x) - v(0)$.  Well, since $v'(t)$ **is** $g(t)$, then we have $v(x) - v(0) = \int_0^x g(t) \, dt$, which gives us $v = \int_0^x g(t) \, dt + v(0)$.  Notice how I'm using $t$ as the variable of integration.  This is because $x$ is a limit of integration, and in general it's very bad form (and personally I would say incorrect) to have a limit of integration be the same as the variable of integration.  And we need the variable of integration to be $x$ because $v$ is a function of $x$.

Note that the $f'(x) \, dx$ in the integral on the RHS above is ok, because it's the *inner* integral that has $x$ as a limit, but the $f'(x) \, dx$ is for the *outer* integral.  In fact, this actually has to be $f'(x)\, dx$ because if we were to evaluate $\int_0^x g(t) \, dt + v(0)$, we would get a function of $x$.  Therefore the outer integral needs to be $dx$, which means we must have $f'(x) \, dx$ in order for this to work out.

---

Example:  $ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} x \cos x \, dx$

I'll run through this twice.  Once how we would do it in practice, and then again in a manner similar to how I explained above.

**In practice:**

$u = x, \qquad dv = \cos x \, dx$

$du = dx, \qquad v = \int \cos x \, dx = \sin x$

Note the lack of arbitrary constant of integration on $v$.  It's because it always cancels out in the end anyway, so for simplicity we just don't bother with it.  Anyway, plugging everything into the formula gives us:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \underbrace{x}_{\color{red}{u}} \underbrace{\cos x \, dx}_{\color{red}{dv}} = \underbrace{x}_{\color{red}{u}}\underbrace{(\sin x)}_{\color{red}{v}}\bigg|_0^{\pi/2} - \int_0^{\pi/2} \underbrace{\sin x}_{\color{red}{v}} \, \underbrace{dx}_{\color{red}{du}}$$

**Similar to my explanation above:**

$u = x, \qquad dv = \cos x \, dx$

$du = dx, \qquad v = \int_0^x \cos t \, dt + v(0)$

Let's take a closer look at $v$.  We have
\begin{align}
  v &= \int_0^x \cos t \, dt + v(0)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \underbrace{\sin t}_{\color{blue}{\text{this is $v(t)$}}}\bigg|_0^x + \underbrace{v(0)}_{\substack{\color{blue}{\text{therefore}} \\ \color{blue}{v(0) = \sin 0}}}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \underbrace{\sin x - \sin 0 + \sin 0}_{\color{blue}{v(x) - v(0) + v(0)}}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sin x
\end{align}

Notice how the $+v(0)$ is necessary to cancel out the $-v(0)$. And yes, in this case it wouldn't have mattered because $v(0) = 0$ anyway, but that won't be true in general so we do need to be careful.  But again, in practice what we do is actually much simpler, and I only wrote my answer this way to show what's really happening behind the scenes and so I could avoid notational issues in the double integral near the end.

Comment: Ok, so how am I supposed to obtain $v(0)$?

Comment: @titanium, if you actually have a specific (and nice enough) function $g$ to work with then you can simply evaluate $v = \int g(x) \, dx$ like how we normally do when doing integration by parts.  The $+v(0)$ in practice will "cancel" with the $-v(0)$ from the integral, leaving you with just $v(x)$.  I included it here to be thorough and to avoid notational issues later on.  I'll update my answer to include an example that will hopefully help to explain this.

Comment: ok. That is helpful, thanks.