# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\frac{G\ln 2}{2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In order to compute, in an **elementary way**,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan x \log \left( 1-x^2\right)}{1+x^2}dx$

(see  [Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan x \log \left( 1-x^2\right)}{1+x^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542741/evaluating-int-01-fracx-arctan-x-log-left-1-x2-right1x2dx))

i need to show, in a **simple way**, that:

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}$

$G$ is the Catalan's constant.

PS:

This formula is equivalent to:

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}$

It's not a trivial formula for me.

PS2:

$\displaystyle \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)=\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)-\ln(\cos x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)$

Compare to:

$\displaystyle \ln(\cos x-\sin x)\ln(\cos x) dx-\ln(\cos x+\sin x)\ln(\sin x)$

Comment: what do you mean by simple? what have you tried?

Comment: Simple: change of variable, integration by parts, use of symmetry... Anyway, post your solution if you have any. I have tried the methods from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850830/evaluating-int-0-tfrac-pi4-ln-cos-x-sin-x-ln-cos-x-dx-int-0-t

Comment: I think the simple way is just to exploit http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos

Comment: Too complex for me. I was hoping desperately there is a tricky simple way to compute it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850830/evaluating-int-0-tfrac-pi4-ln-cos-x-sin-x-ln-cos-x-dx-int-0-t?rq=1
Remembering this?

Comment: These integrals seem linked but one is "elementary", the other one is not that much according to me. Please look at it carefully, they are different.

Comment: Do know how to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\ln(sin(x) \ dx} $ and  $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\ln(cos(x) \ dx} $ ? If you can write it in terms of Catalan's constant.

Comment: here, it's rather $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln(sin x)^2 dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln(cos x)^2 dx$ involved.

Answer (score 6):

Denote $K= \int _0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}x \ln x}{1-x^2}dx
$. Note
\begin{align}
&\int _0^1\frac{\ln x \ln \frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+x^2}dx\\
\overset{ibp}=& \ 2K
 - 2\int _0^1{\frac{\tan^{-1}x \ln \frac{1-x}{1+x}}{x}}
 \overset{x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}}  {dx }=4K +\frac{\pi^3}{16} \tag1
\\ \\
&\int _0^1\frac{\ln x \ln \frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+x^2}dx=\int _0^1 \ln \frac{1-x}{1+x}\> d \left(\int_1^x \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt\right)\\
\overset{ibp}= &\int _0^1 \frac{2}{1-x^2}\left( \int_0^x \right. \overset{t=xs }{\left. \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt+G\right)}dx \\
=&\int_0^1 \frac2{1-x^2}\left( \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x+x\ln s}{1+x^2s^2}ds +G \right)dx 
\\=&\ 2\int_0^1 \bigg(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x }{(1-x^2)(1+x^2s^2)}ds\\
&\hspace{10mm}+ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln s }{1+s^2}
\left(\frac{xs^2}{1+x^2s^2} +\frac x{1-x^2} \right) ds
+\frac G{1-x^2} \bigg)dx 
\\=&\ 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x }{1-x^2}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x }{1+x^2s^2}ds\right)dx \\
&\hspace{10mm}+ 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln s }{1+s^2}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{xs^2  }{1+x^2s^2}dx\right)ds \\
&\hspace{10mm}+2 \int_0^1 \left(-\frac {Gx}{1-x^2}+ \frac G{1-x^2} 
\right)dx \\
=& \int _0^1\frac{\ln s\ln \left(1+s^2\right)}{1+s^2}ds +2K +2G\ln2 \tag2
\end{align}

Combine (1) and (2)
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln s\ln \left(1+s^2\right)}{1+s^2}ds= 2 \left(K + \frac{\pi^3}{32}\right)-2G\ln 2\tag3$$
Next, evaluate
\begin{align}
 K + \frac{\pi^3}{32} =& \int _0^1 \tan^{-1}x\> d \left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}dt\right) + \frac{\pi^3}{32}\\
\overset{ibp}=& - \int_0^1 \frac{dx }{1+x^2}\int_0^x \overset{t=xs} {\frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}}dt \\
=&- \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{ x\ln s }{(1+x^2)(1-x^2s^2)}dsdx \\
& \hspace{15mm} -\int_0^1\int_0^1\overset{x\leftrightarrow s} {\frac{x\ln x }{(1+x^2)(1-x^2s^2)}}dsdx\\
 =&-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s}{1+s^2}\int_0^1 \left(\frac x{1+x^2}+\frac{xs^2}{1-x^2s^2} \right) dx \ ds\\
&\hspace{15mm} - \int_0^1 \int_0^1 { \frac{s\ln s  }{(1+s^2)(1-x^2s^2)} }ds\ dx\\
= &-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s}{1+s^2}ds \int_0^1 \frac {x}{1+x^2}dx \\
&\hspace{15mm}-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s}{1+s^2}\left( \int_0^1 \frac {s}{1-xs}dx\right)ds \\
=& \ \frac12G\ln2 + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln s\ln(1-s)}{1+s^2}ds 
\end{align}
Substitute above expression of $K + \frac{\pi^3}{32} $ into (3) to obtain
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s\ln \frac{(1-s)^2}{1+s^2}}{1+s^2}ds = G\ln 2$$
which, via $s=\tan t$, leads to
$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan t)\ln(\cos t-\sin t)dt=\frac12G\ln 2$$

Comment: elegant as always +1

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x -
> \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
> \half\,\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G}}$.
>   
>   $\ds{\mrm{G}:\ \mbox{Catalan Constant.}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x -
\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x -
\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x\ic} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$\ds{\ln}$-function branch-cut is chosen along the 'negative real axis'. Namely, in $\ds{\left.\vphantom{\large A}\ln\pars{z}\right\vert_{\ z\ \not=\ 0}}$ we have $\ds{-\pi < \mrm{arg}\pars{z} < \pi}$. For instance, when $\ds{x \in \pars{0,1}}$ we have:
\begin{align}
\ln\pars{1 + \ic x} & =
\ln\pars{\root{1 + x^{2}}} + \arctan\pars{x}\ic =
\ol{\bracks{\ln\pars{\root{1 + x^{2}}} - \arctan\pars{x}\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
\ol{\ln\pars{1 - x\ic}}
\\[5mm] \mbox{and}\ \ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} & =
\ln\pars{1 + x\ic} + \ln\pars{1 - x\ic} = 2\,\Re\ln\pars{1 + x\ic}\quad
\mbox{which we already used in \eqref{1}}.
\end{align}

---

With the identity
$\ds{ab = \half\,a^{2} + \half\,b^{2} - \half\,\pars{a - b}^{2}}$, the expression \eqref{1} can be rewritten in the form
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x -
\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\overbrace{\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{1}}}}\
\overbrace{-\,\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x/\bracks{1 - x}} \over 1 + x^{2}}
\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{2}}}}\
\overbrace{-
\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x\ic} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{3}}}}
\\[5mm] + &\ \underbrace{%
\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x/\bracks{1 + x\ic}} \over 1 + x^{2}}
\,\dd x}_{\ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{4}}}}\ =\
\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{1}} + \color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{2}} +\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{3}} +\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{4}}
\end{align}

> It turns out that the above integrals can be reduced to the form
>   $$
> \left.\int{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over a - x}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ \not=\ 0}
> \,\,\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ =\ at}{=}\,\,\,\,\,
> \int{\ln^{2}\pars{at} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t =
> -\int\ln^{2}\pars{at}\,\dd\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - t}}
> $$
>   which can be *easily* evaluated by successive integration by parts:
>   \begin{equation}
> \int{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over a - x}\,\dd x =
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
> \ds{-\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - {x \over a}} -
> 2\ln\pars{x}\Li{2}\pars{x \over a} + 2\Li{3}\pars{x \over a}} & \mbox{if} &
> \ds{a \not= 0}
> \\
> \ds{-\,{1 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{x}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{a = 0}
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{equation}
>   $$
> \begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
> \quad\mbox{Hereafter, we'll use this result to evaluate}\
> \ds{\braces{\vphantom{\large A}\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{k}}\,,\ k = 1,2,3,4}}
> \quad
> \\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

---

> With $\ds{r \equiv 1 + \ic}$:

1. $\ds{\large\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{1}}:\ ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{1}} & \equiv
   \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\,\,\,\,
   \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ \pars{1 - x}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,
   \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{x - r}\pars{x - \ol{r}}}\,\dd x =
   -\,\half\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over r - x}\,\dd x =
   \color{#f00}{\Im\Li{3}\pars{\half\,r}}\label{J1}\tag{J1}
   \end{align}

   ---
2. $\ds{\large\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{2}}:\ ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{2}} & \equiv
   -\,\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x/\bracks{1 - x}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
   \,\,\,\,\,\stackrel{x/\pars{1 - x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,\,\,
   -\,\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 2x^{2} + 2x + 1}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\,\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 2x^{2} + 2x + 1}\,\dd x -
   \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 2x + 2}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}
   {\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{x + r/2}\pars{x + \ol{r}/2}}\,\dd x - \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{x + r}\pars{x + \ol{r}}}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\,\half\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over -r/2 - x}\,\dd x -
   \half\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over -r - x}\,\dd x
   \end{align}
   However,
   $$
   \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
   \ds{-\,\half\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over -r/2 - x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\,{5 \over 128}\,\pi^{3} - {1 \over 32}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi -
   \Im\Li{3}\pars{-\,{r \over 2}}}
   \\[3mm]
   \ds{-\,\half\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over -r - x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\Im\Li{3}\pars{-\,{\ol{r} \over 2}}}
   \end{array}\right.
   $$
   Then,
   \begin{equation}
   \color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{2}} =
   \color{#f00}{-\,{5 \over 128}\,\pi^{3} - {1 \over 32}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi}
   \label{J2}\tag{J2}
   \end{equation}

   ---
3. $\ds{\large\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{3}}:\ ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{3}} & \equiv
   -\,\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x\ic} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
   \,\,\,\,\,\stackrel{\pars{1 + x\ic}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}
   -\,\half\,\Im\int_{1}^{r}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{2 - x}x}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\,{1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{1}^{r}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 2 - x}\,\dd x -
   {1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{1}^{r}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
   \end{align}
   The remaining integrals are given by:
   $$
   \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
   \ds{-\,{1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{1}^{r}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 2 - x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &
   \ds{{1 \over 96}\,\pi^{3} - {3 \over 32}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi +
   {1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G} - \half\,\Im\Li{3}\pars{r \over 2}}
   \\[3mm]
   \ds{-\,{1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{1}^{r}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
   & \ds{=} &
   \ds{{1 \over 768}\,\pi^{3} - {1 \over 64}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\,\pi}
   \end{array}\right.
   $$
   Then,
   \begin{equation}
   \color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{3}} =
   \color{#f00}{{3 \over 256}\,\pi^{3} - {7 \over 64}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi +
   {1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G} - \half\,\Im\Li{3}\pars{r \over 2}}
   \label{J3}\tag{J3}
   \end{equation}

   ---
4. $\ds{\large\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{4}}:\ ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{4}} & \equiv
   \half\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x/\bracks{1 + x\ic}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
   \,\,\,\,\,\stackrel{x/\pars{1 + x\ic}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,\,\,
   {1 \over 4}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\ol{r}/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over -\ic/2 - x}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   \color{#f00}{{7 \over 256}\,\pi^{3} + {9 \over 64}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi +
   {1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G} - \half\,\Im\Li{3}\pars{r \over 2}}
   \label{J4}\tag{J4}
   \end{align}

   ---

   Summarising
   $\ds{\pars{~\vphantom{\large A}\mbox{see}\ \eqref{J1}, \eqref{J2}, \eqref{J3}\ \mbox{and}\ \eqref{J4}~}}$:
   \begin{equation}
   \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcccccccc}
   \ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{1}}} & \ds{=} &&&&&&&\ds{\Im\Li{3}\pars{r \over 2}}
   \\[3mm]
   \ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{2}}} & \ds{=} &
   \ds{-\,{5 \over 128}\,\pi^{3}} & \ds{-} & \ds{{1 \over 32}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi}
   &&&&
   \\[3mm]
   \ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{3}}} & \ds{=} &
   \ds{{3 \over 256}\,\pi^{3}} & \ds{-} & \ds{{7 \over 64}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi} & \ds{+} &
   \ds{{1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G}} & \ds{-} &
   \ds{\half\,\Im\Li{3}\pars{r \over 2}}
   \\[3mm]
   \ds{\color{#f00}{\mc{J}_{4}}} & \ds{=} &
   \ds{{7 \over 256}\,\pi^{3}} & \ds{+} & \ds{{9 \over 64}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi} & \ds{+} &
   \ds{{1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G}} & \ds{-} & \ds{\half\,\Im\Li{3}\pars{r \over 2}}
   \end{array}\right.
   \end{equation}
   The $\ds{\quad\ul{final\ result}\quad}$ is given by:
   \begin{align}
   &\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x -
   \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
   \\[5mm] = &\
   \mc{J}_{1} + \mc{J}_{2} + \mc{J}_{3} + \mc{J}_{4} =
   \color{#f00}{\half\,\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{G}}\,,\qquad
   \pars{~\mrm{G}:\ \mbox{Catalan Constant}~}
   \end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Following is the proof that,

\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}
\end{equation*}

Knowing that,
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \beta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}
\end{equation*}

then,
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{\arctan x\ln x}{x}dx=-\beta(3)
\end{equation*}

(series expansion of  $\dfrac{\arctan x}{x}$)

Let,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle A&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\arctan x\ln x}{1+x^2}dx\\
\displaystyle B&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x \ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\\
\displaystyle C&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}dx
\end{align*}

Let $R$ the function defined on $[0;1]$ such that for all $x$ in $[0;1]$,

\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle R(x)=\int_0^x \dfrac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(tx)}{1+t^2x^2}dt
\end{equation*}

Let $\epsilon$ such that  $0<\epsilon<1$.
\begin{align*}
\varphi(\epsilon)&=\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\Big[\left(R(x)-R(1)\right)\ln(1-x)\Big]_0^{1-\epsilon}+\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\dfrac{\left(R(x)-R(1)\right)}{1-x}dx\\
&=\displaystyle \left(R(1-\epsilon)-R(1)\right)\ln(\epsilon)+R(1)\ln(\epsilon)+\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\dfrac{R(x)}{1-x}dx\\
&=\displaystyle \left(R(1-\epsilon)-R(1)\right)\ln(\epsilon)+R(1)\ln(\epsilon)+\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \left(\dfrac{x\ln(tx)}{(1+t^2x^2)(1-x)}dt\right)dx\\
&=\displaystyle \left(R(1-\epsilon)-R(1)\right)\ln(\epsilon)+R(1)\ln(\epsilon)+\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \left(\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln x}{(1+t^2x^2)(1-x)}dt\right)dx+\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \dfrac{x\ln t}{(1+t^2x^2)(1-x)}dx\right)dt\\
&=\displaystyle \left(R(1-\epsilon)-R(1)\right)\ln(\epsilon)+R(1)\ln(\epsilon)+\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \left[\dfrac{\ln x\arctan(tx)}{1-x}\right]_{t=0}^{t=1}dx+\\
&\int_0^1 \left[\dfrac{\ln t\ln(1+t^2x^2)}{2(1+t^2)}+\dfrac{t\ln t\arctan(tx)}{1+t^2}-\dfrac{\ln t\arctan(tx)}{t}-\dfrac{\ln t\ln(1-x)}{1+t^2}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1-\epsilon} dt\\
&=\displaystyle \left(R(1-\epsilon)-R(1)\right)\ln(\epsilon)+R(1)\ln(\epsilon)+\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \dfrac{\ln x\arctan(x)}{1-x}dx+\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln t\ln\left(1+t^2(1-\epsilon)^2\right)}{2(1+t^2)}dt+\\
&\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\dfrac{t\ln t\arctan\left(t(1-\epsilon)\right)}{1+t^2}dt-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln t\arctan\left(t(1-\epsilon)\right)}{t}dt-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln t\ln \epsilon}{1+t^2}dt\\
&=\displaystyle \left(R(1-\epsilon)-R(1)\right)\ln(\epsilon)+\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \dfrac{\ln x\arctan(x)}{1-x}dx+\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln t\ln\left(1+t^2(1-\epsilon)^2\right)}{2(1+t^2)}dt+\\
&\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\dfrac{t\ln t\arctan\left(t(1-\epsilon)\right)}{1+t^2}dt-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln t\arctan\left(t(1-\epsilon)\right)}{t}dt
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\varphi(\epsilon)=\int_0^{1} \dfrac{\ln x\arctan(x)}{1-x}dx+\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln t\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{2(1+t^2)}dt+\int_0^{1}\dfrac{t\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}dt-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln t\arctan t}{t}dt
\end{equation*}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
(1)\boxed{\displaystyle\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx=A+\dfrac{1}{2}B+\beta(3)+\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x }{1-x}dx }
\end{equation}

In the following integral apply the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan(x)}{1-x}dx&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\left(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)\right)\arctan\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{x}dx+\int_0^1 \dfrac{\left(\ln(1-x)-\ln(1+x)\right)\arctan\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{1+x}dx\\
&=\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(1+x)\arctan x}{x}dx-\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(1-x)\arctan x}{x}dx-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln\left(\tfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{x}dx+\\
&\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln\left(\tfrac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\arctan\left(\tfrac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{1+x}dx
\end{align*}

and,

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(1+x)\arctan x}{x}dx&=\Big[\ln x\ln(1+x)\arctan x\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1\ln x\left(\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{\arctan x}{1+x}\right)dx\\
&=\displaystyle -\int_0^1  \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x) }{1+x^2}dx-C
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(1-x)\arctan x}{x}dx&=\Big[\ln x\ln(1-x)\arctan x\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1\ln x\left(\dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}-\dfrac{\arctan x}{1-x}\right)dx\\
&=\displaystyle \int_0^1  \dfrac{\ln x\arctan x }{1-x}dx-\int_0^1  \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x) }{1+x^2}dx
\end{align*}

In the following integral apply the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln\left(\tfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{x}dx&=-2\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx\\
&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align*}

In the following integral apply the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,

\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln\left(\tfrac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\arctan\left(\tfrac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}{1+x}dx=-C
\end{equation*}

Thus,

\begin{equation*}
(2)\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan(x)}{1-x}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-C-\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}}
\end{equation*}

Let $S$ the function defined on $[0;1]$ such that for all $x$ in $[0;1]$,,

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle S(x)&=\int_0^x\dfrac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dt\\
&=\int_0^1\dfrac{x\ln(tx)}{1+t^2x^2}dt
\end{align*}

Note that $S(1)=-G$, $G$ being the Catalan constant,

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx&=\Big[S(x)\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1 \dfrac{S(x)}{1+x}dx\\
&=-G\ln 2-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(tx)}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x)}dtdx\\
&=-G\ln 2-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln x}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x)}dtdx-\!\!\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln t}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x)}dtdx\\
&=-G\ln 2-\!\!\!\int_0^1\left[\dfrac{\ln x\arctan(tx)}{1+x}\right]_{t=0}^{t=1}dx-\\
&\int_0^1\!\!\left[\dfrac{\ln t\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{2(1+t^2)}\!-\!\!\dfrac{\ln t\ln(1+x)}{1+t^2}\!-\!\!\dfrac{t\ln t\arctan(tx)}{1+t^2}\!+\!\!\dfrac{\ln t\arctan(tx)}{t}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\!dt\\
&=-G\ln 2-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x}dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln t\ln(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}dt+\\
&\ln 2\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^1\dfrac{t\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}dt-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln t\arctan t}{t}dt\\
\end{align*}

Thus,

\begin{equation*}
(3)\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=A-\dfrac{1}{2}B-C-2G\ln 2+\beta(3)}
\end{equation*}

Let $T$ the function defined on $[0;1]$ such that for all $x$ in $[0;1]$,

\begin{align*} 
\displaystyle T(y)&=\int_0^y \dfrac{t\ln(t)}{1+t^2}dt\\
&=\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{ty^2\ln(ty)}{1+t^2y^2}dt
\end{align*}

Note that $T(1)=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{48}$

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle A&=\Big[T(y)\arctan y\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1 \dfrac{S(y)}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\displaystyle-\dfrac{\pi^3}{192}-\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{ty^2\ln(ty)}{(1+t^2y^2)(1+y^2)}dtdy\\
\displaystyle &=-\dfrac{\pi^3}{192}-\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{ty^2\ln y }{(1+t^2y^2)(1+y^2)}dtdy-\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{ty^2\ln t }{(1+t^2y^2)(1+y^2)}dtdy\\
\displaystyle &=-\dfrac{\pi^3}{192}-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left[\dfrac{\ln y \ln(1+t^2y^2)}{1+y^2}\right]_{t=0}^{t=1}dy-\\
&\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left[\dfrac{\ln t \arctan y+\ln t\arctan(ty)}{1+t}-\dfrac{\ln t \arctan(ty)-\ln t\arctan y}{t-1}\right]_{y=0}^{y=1}dt
\end{align*}

Thus,
\begin{align*}
(4)\boxed{\displaystyle A=-\dfrac{1}{64}\pi^3-\dfrac{1}{2}B-\dfrac{1}{2}C-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x}{1-x}dx}
\end{align*}

Plug $\displaystyle \int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx$ from (1) and 
$\displaystyle \int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$ from (4) into (2),

Thus,

\begin{align*}
(5)\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x}{1-x}dx=B-C+2G\ln 2-\dfrac{1}{16}\pi^3}
\end{align*}

Plug $\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x}{1-x}dx$ from (5) into (4)

Thus,

\begin{align*}
(6)\boxed{A=\dfrac{1}{64}\pi^3-B-G\ln 2}
\end{align*}

In the following integral apply the change of variable $y=\arctan x$,

\begin{align*}
(7) \boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx-\dfrac{B}{2}}
\end{align*}

and, from (1), it follows that,

\begin{align*}
(8) \boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=A+\beta(3)-\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x}{1-x}dx}
\end{align*}

Plug $A$ from (6) and $\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln \arctan x}{1-x}dx$ from (5) into (7),

\begin{align*}
(8) \boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=-\dfrac{3}{64}\pi^3+G\ln 2+\beta(3)-C}
\end{align*}

$C$ have been already evaluated (see [Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \log x}{1+x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842284/evaluating-int-01-frac-arctan-x-log-x1xdx/1842492#1842492) )

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\displaystyle C=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}-\dfrac{\pi^3}{64}}
\end{equation}

and, knowing that,

\begin{equation}
 \beta(3)=\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{equation}

Therefore,

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx
\end{align}
For the first integral, We proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281259):

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{3\pi^3}{64}+\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^22-\Im\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i)$$

and for the second integral, we proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211825):

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac3{32}\pi^3+\frac{\pi}8\ln^22-\ln2~G-2\Im\operatorname{Li_3}(1+i)$$

and by combining these two results, we get $\ \displaystyle I=\frac12G\ln2$

Comment: $+1$. You have your own library. Great job.

Comment: @Felix Marin thank you :)