# Hard triple Integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2-zx^{2}-zy^{2}}dxdydz=\ln(2^{G})$

Tags: integration

How do prove this triple integral?
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2-zx^{2}-zy^{2}}dxdydz=\ln(2^{G})$$
where G is Catalan's constant.

As my try I only reach to this hard single integral:
$$\int _0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=G\ln \left(2\right)$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Invisible Changing the order of integral does not make any sense. because all 3 integral have same orders.

Comment: It does make sense as the integrand is not symmetric. It may be fruitful to first integrate wrt $z$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate by parts

$$I=\int _0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx
= \frac{\pi^3}{24}+\int_0^1\frac{2x\tan^{-1}x\ln\frac{1-x^2}2}{1+x^2}dx$$
Then, utilize [$\int_0^1 \frac{x \tan^{-1} x \ln \left( 1-x^2\right)}{1+x^2}dx=  -\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^2 2 +G\ln 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/542741/686284) and $\int_0^1 \frac{x\tan^{-1}x}{1+x^2}dx = \frac12G-\frac\pi2\ln2$ to obtain $I= G\ln2$.

Comment: Nice solution! but there is a type in your solution.